# Passing default date range to ng bootstrap dateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass the default date range to ng bootstrap date range picker. Input field doesn't get updated.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.startDate = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
    this.maxDate = { year: now.getFullYear() + 1, month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
    this.minDate = {year: now.getFullYear() - 1, month: now.getMonth() + 1, day: now.getDate()};
    let parsed = ' '
    this.fromDate = this.ngbCalendar.getToday();
    this.toDate = this.ngbCalendar.getNext(this.ngbCalendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
    if(this.fromDate) {
      parsed += this._parserFormatter.format(this.fromDate);
    }
    if(this.toDate) {
      parsed += ' - ' + this._parserFormatter.format(this.toDate);
    }
    //passing default date
    this.model = parsed;
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.myRangeInput.nativeElement, 'value', parsed);
   }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skbpc8-f1islo?file=app/datepicker-popup.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[(ngModel)]` from the html.